# Tracking a page for redirection with a session variable

Tags: php, session-variables

I am currently using a SESSION variable for redirection. Hoprfully code snippets will make it clear.

**addForm.php:**

```
if (!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
            if (isset($_COOKIE['username'])){   
                $_SESSION['myusername'] = $_COOKIE['username'];

            }
        else{   
                #using a session var to redirect back to addForm.php
                $_SESSION['addForm'] = 1;
                header("location:loginForm.php");       
            }
}
```

**LoginSuccess.php**

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_COOKIE['username'])){

    header("location:loginForm.php");
}
if (isset($_SESSION['addForm'])){
    header("location:addForm.php");
}
```

the above works (redirects to addForm.php). My question is, are there any risks in doing it this way? is there a better way to do it? I guess i'm looking for 'best practice'.

Comment: Sorry, i lost the question bit on a random page refresh. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have some errors:

1. The valid header is `header('Location: http://www.example.org/script.php');` notice `L` and full URL?
2. After each `header('Location: http://www.example.org/script.php');` it should be `exit();`
3. You cannot rely just on `$_COOKIE['username']`, you need to have something from password, I mean not the password, maybe an `MD5()` hashed password in `$_COOKIE` also. And you should know not to rely on `$_COOKIE` that much.
4. In `LoginSuccess.php` you have to `unset($_SESSION['addForm'])` before redirection, `addForm` from session will still be set.

Comment: Thanks for the tips. With regard to point 1. I am able to use 'location' instead of 'Location' with no errors. Any reason why this is the case?

Comment: It's not for your code language, it's for browser. The browser receives header as `location`. Standards are `Location` as header, no matter programming language.

Answer (score 1):

Personnaly, I prefer store the entry current URI in session varible. Then, when my login process are successfull, I use the stored URI to redirect the user to the previous page.

**Pseudo Code**

```
    if (!isset($_SESSION['userloginobj'])) {
        $_SESSION['callbackuri'] = get_current_url_depending_of_your_process();
        header('location:' . get_base_url() . 'index.php?do=login');
        exit(0);
    }
    elseif ('login' == get_param('do')) {
        // Show the login form

        if ( is_login_successfull() ) {
             $_SESSION['userloginobj'] = "userinfo";
             header('location:' . $_SESSION['callbackurl']);
             exit(0);
        }
    }
    else {
        // Normal process
    }
```

But your proccess seems to be a good start if you don't use a framework.